# How can I check if a service has been instantiated via Ninject?

Tags: c#, ninject

I'm using Ninject in my intergration tests to create instances of stuff my tests need.

I want to run some clean up code in the Tear Down method of the test, but only if a particular service has been instantiated via the Kernel.

I'm looking for something similar to this:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IMyService>.To<MyService>();

var x = kernel.HasBeenInstantiated<IMyService>();
// x == false;

var myservice = kernel.Get<IMyService>();

var y = kernel.HasBeenInstantiated<IMyService>();
// y == true;
```

Is there a way I can check to see if a particular service has been instantiated?

Comment: Why would you ever overcomplicate unit tests with a DI container? The `new` operator works just fine as you are only instantiating mocks for the most part. Makes cleanup a snap, too.

Comment: I'm using Effort (http://entityframework-effort.net/) as an in-mem test database, and a few other things. Ninject has greatly simplified my unit test setup

Comment: If you have an in memory database, then it is an *integration* test, not a unit test (and a DI container would be more appropriate). You should probably clarify your question.

Comment: Ok, done.......